# Disabling a custom date field along with the calendar button right next to it, through client script in suitescript 2.0

Tags: javascript, inline, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In my `fieldChanged` function, I m trying to DISABLE a date field through `field.isDisabled = true;`
The field gets disabled but the small calendar button on the right remains as it is, which lets the user select the date in the field.

My Code is:

```
if (cusStatus == 2 || cusStatus == 4 || cusStatus == 7) {
  var compDate = currRec.getField({ fieldId: 'custrecord_sn_trf_dateoperation' });
  compDate.isDisabled = true;
}
```

This works fine and disables the field, but the calendar button(on the right in the below image) remains there.

[image]

and user can even set the value through the calendar.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to disable/remove this calendar?

Comment: You could reject the change for that field in fieldChanged if the field is disabled.

Comment: yes, thank you Brian, but any idea of how to make that calender option vanish?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply customize the form and hide that field.

Go to your transaction and then click on Customise -> Customise Form at the top right corner of the transaction:
[image]

Go to the Screen Fields subtab and find your date field, uncheck the "Show" checkbox and the field should be hidden:
[image]

Good luck!